# Multiline \institute has no spacing in Beamerposter footline

Tags: beamer, spacing, line-spacing, beamerposter

I've implemented a custom theme to provide institute information in the footline of my poster. It works fine in practice, but the spacing between lines is way off if the lines don't include characters that go above and below the basic line height, i.e. the height of say "e". So I've resorted in a phantom-reverse-phantom command to force high and low letters. However, when I insert the institute in normal text or a similar environment outside the footline, the spacing is fine. Am I missing something? Removing the surrounding minipage helps too, but I want to restrict the width. And again, no such issue with the minipage outside of the footline either.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[final,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=2,debug]{beamerposter}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{cvprl}}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

% Use phantom and reverse with negphantom to enforce consistent spacing between text rows
% that don't have characters that would dip below or rise above normal text.
\newcommand{\cvprlnegphantom}[1]{\settowidth{\dimen0}{#1}\hspace*{-\dimen0}}
\newcommand{\cvprlaligntext}{\phantom{Tj}\cvprlnegphantom{Tj}}

\institute{
    lots\\
    of\\
    institutes\\
}

%\institute{
%    \cvprlaligntext lots\\
%    \cvprlaligntext of\\
%    \cvprlaligntext institutes\\
%}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\insertinstitute

% Footline duplicate
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{footline}
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{\paperwidth}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth]{footlinesep}\vspace{1em}\end{beamercolorbox}
    \vskip 2em
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}
        \usebeamercolor{institute}{\color{fg}\large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}
    \end{minipage}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{beamercolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

% beamerthemecvprl.sty:
\ProvidesPackage{cvprl}
\mode<all>

\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{footlinesep}{fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{institute}{fg=black}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{footline}
    \begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{\paperwidth}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth]{footlinesep}\vspace{1em}\end{beamercolorbox}
        \vskip 2em
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}
            \usebeamercolor{institute}{\color{fg}\large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

Here's how the main content looks like:

[image: main content spacing is fine]

And here's the footline:

[image: footline spacing is missing]

What could I do to fix this? I really dislike hacking the system like this.

Comment: Sometimes, such line-spacing issues happen because the text has not been ended by a `\par`. I can't tell whether this could be a problem here, since I don't have your template. Maybe placing `\par` directly before `\end{minipage}` helps?

Comment: I did include everything in the example, but having tested `\par` it does work! Although now the spacing is a bit larger than what I would've liked, closer to the first example just with a bigger font, rather than the copied column/minipage setup. But I'll take it, thanks a bunch!

Comment: size commands do not take an argument so `\large{\insertinstitute}` would make the rest of the document `\large` if it were not scoped by the footline, they also need `\par` so the paragraph uses the correct line spacing so it should be `{\large \insertinstitute\par}` and shouldn't be followed by `\\[1ex]` which presumably gives underful hbox warnings.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Much appreciated!